# Animate a flying bird in p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I want to create an animation of a bird with p5 js. I have 6 pictures of the bird - when the wings are up, in the middle, and so on... When I press 'space bar' on the keyboard, the bird should fly - so all the pics should be shown as an animation (as if the bird is really flying). I want to build this code snippet without spritemap.
This is my code, but somehow it doesn't work..

```
let time = 0;
let frame = 0;
let img = [];

function preload() {
  img.push(loadImage("assets/Bird/bird-1.png"));
  img.push(loadImage("assets/Bird/bird-2.png"));
  img.push(loadImage("assets/Bird/bird-3.png"));
  img.push(loadImage("assets/Bird/bird-4.png"));
  img.push(loadImage("assets/Bird/bird-5.png"));
}

function draw() {

  function keyPressed() {
    if (key == ' ') {
      const speed = 1;
      const numImage = img.length;
      let current = frame % numImage;
      let display = img[current];
      image(display, width / 2, height / 2, display.width, display.length);
      time += speed;
        if (time > 5) {
          time = 0;
          frame++;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Looking forward to reading some ideas! Thank you in advance.

Comment: key is undefined, please edit your question and add more code, like the one you use to add a listener to get the key pressed. I guess you need to use setTimeout to run the animation.

Answer (score 1):

First things first you should not need to handle frames and such things. It is better to use `keyPressed` function outside of scope `draw` since it is a special event function and automatically called when a key is pressed.

It is better to use `setup` functionality instead of `preload` since preload is a little bit more early function then we needed. Setup is more relevant in such things like loading an array and so on.

I see that you forgot to create a canvas to draw an image on it. I added that on setup and also set the framerate of canvas regarding the `img` array's size.

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  background(51);

  img.push(loadImage("1.png"));
  img.push(loadImage("2.png"));
  img.push(loadImage("3.png"));
  img.push(loadImage("4.png"));

  frameRate(img.length * 2); // double speed on animate sprites
}
```

From this point it is only a matter of checking the `keyCode` and looping through array.

```js
function draw() {
  if (keyIsDown(32)) {
    background(51);
    const numImage = img.length;
    let current = frameCount % numImage;
    let display = img[current];
    image(display, width / 2 - display.width , height / 2 - display.height , display.width, display.length);
  }
}
```

Here in the `keyIsDown(32)` check, `32` represents spacebar. You can check others from here easily : http://keycode.info/

You want to re-set the background of canvas on each sprite display. If not, they will still be showing on each render.

You can see the working version of your code in here : 
https://editor.p5js.org/darcane/sketches/rVl22hkv7